# An expression like one-two punch, but good?

Tags: expressions, idioms, phrase-requests

Is there an expression to describe the following?

> The first thing is good, the second one builds the first; the two things go better together. Like socks and shoes, but with more gravitas.

Comment: sort of like drill and drill bit or hammer and nail.

Comment: The question should be improved to get better answers. However, I may propose "Symbiosys" or "synergy".

Comment: _The old one-two_ is equally informal: _one-two_  2.
Informal. any strong or effective combination of two people or things:
_The old one-two of a good passer and a good receiver is the best way to win football games._ {[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/one-two)}

Comment: Like Soup and Sandwich?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [The Old One-Two](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the+old+one+two). the Urban Dictionary provides some interesting synonyms, or at least 'words associated with it, but says nothing about its etymology.

Comment: "The whole is greater than the sum of its parts". *This Aristotle quote became a common phrase in English*.

Comment: You might want to be more specific about what you mean by "but good". One-two punch is often used with positive connotations.

Comment: The "one-two punch" doesn't have to have a negative connotation.  If you're the one *delivering* the blows, then the phrase precisely meets your needs.  Just make sure the context makes it clear that you mean it positively, and I don't think anyone will question it.  [example](https://bookmarketingtools.com/blog/benefit-of-self-publishing-with-createspace-and-ingram-spark/)

Answer (score 0):

This is often described as the **icing on the cake**, meaning an additional benefit on top of something already good.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/icing+on+the+cake

Answer (score 0):

There is a metaphor relating to the gradual building of philosophies or scientific theories by different contributors:

> If [we] have seen further, it is by standing on the shoulders of
>   giants.

[Used by Newton; here translated into Modern English.]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants) explain:

> The metaphor of dwarfs standing on the shoulders of giants (Latin:
>   nanos gigantum humeris insidentes) expresses the meaning of
>   "discovering truth by building on previous discoveries". While it can
>   be traced to at least the 12th century, attributed to Bernard of
>   Chartres, its most familiar expression in English is found in a 1676
>   letter of Isaac Newton.